# Appium unable find element by xpath dynamically

Tags: java, android, appium

I have one issue which I can't resolve, I'm trying to write automated tests with Appium to choose an image from the gallery. So I decided to find an element by XPath but the content-desc to inform time is always changing.

```
//android.widget.LinearLayout[@content-desc="image_automation.jpg, 6.00 KB, 15:52"]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.ImageView[1]
```

Also, the item has an attribute resource-id

```
com.google.android.documentsui:id/icon_thumb
```

So I create the script to find the resource-id with content-desc that only inform the image name file, I left "6.00 KB, 15:52" and when I run the output give error NoSuchElementException.

It's my sript:

```
String photo = "//*[@resource-id='com.google.android.documentsui:id/icon_thumb' and contains(@content-desc,'image_automation.jpg')]";
driver.findElementByXPath(photo)
```

Comment: You've tried `//*[contains(@resource-id, 'icon_thumb') and contains(@content-desc, 'image_automation.jpg')]` ?

Comment: @frianH still org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException